# Fullscreen app prevents hotkeys

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen, hotkeys

I've developed a WPF application that registers Hotkeys using com interop and processes them using WndProc.

The hotkeys work perfectly even when the application doesn't have focus. However, they don't work when certain fullscreen appications have focus (games). Is there a way for me to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not.  Hard to guess what 'usomg com' looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disabling of hotkeys is by design and as far as I know not much you can do about it.

Full screen DirectX applications (typically games) will call IDirectDraw::SetCooperativeLevel with the DDSCL_FULLSCREEN and DDSCL_EXCLUSIVE flags which results in, amongst other things, the registered hotkeys being disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Even though registered hotkeys are disabled, you might be able to process your hotkeys via a low level keyboard hook.  They can be kind of tricky to implement right, but you can look at the [AutoHotkey source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120329185939/http://www.autohotkey.com:80/download/OtherDownloads.htm) to see how it handles hotkeys in a low level keyboard hook.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217145327/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) is a good tutorial on setting up a low level keyboard hook in C#.